# listview filter in android

Tags: search, android-listview, filter, android-edittext

I am making an application with Edittext and Listview in android app.
When I search text in edittext then the listview will filter all the words that start with that text.
Example:

- apple
- application
- book an
- can

when i type: a , the result i want is to filter all the word that start with a only:

- apple
- application

when I use : adapterlv.getFilter().filter(txtword.getText());
it filter all the word that contain a.
So, how can i do this?

Comment: Override getFilter() in your Adapter class.

Comment: how can i do this? pls tell me more detail